# Simple Inverse Z-Transform

Tags: z-transform

I'm kind of confused on how to get the inverse Z-transform of basic things. We were told to basically break down the function into smaller parts that we know the z-transform of but I can't find a list of this or any info on this. The problem is

Find the inverse z-transform of H(z) = 1 + z^-1
The answer is h_n = {1, 1}
I have no idea how that answer was gotten. Any ideas?

(This is for a FIR filter btw)

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your confusion.  If you know $h(n)=\delta_0(n)$ and $H(z)=1$ then you should be able to work in both directions.

Recall that $H(z) = G(z)/z$ implies $h(n)=g(n-1)$

Comment: Not sure what that means but I'm having trouble with finding the inverse z-transform when given a discrete signal. How do I find the inverse z-transform of H(z) = 1+z^-1

Comment: Ive given all the hints you need to know. Everything else is just thinking and trying.